# Understanding how list.sort() is working with a lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I was wondering what and how the sort() method was sorting the items in the following list:

```
scores = [('COLIN', 58), ('AMANDBA', 172), ('AMANDAB', 172), ('CAROL', 270), ('PauL', 108), ('JOSEPH', 79)]
```

Here is where I start getting confused:

```
scores.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1],x[0]))
```

So from my understanding what the lambda is basically doing is telling .sort() to sort it by... as an example I'll take the first item from scores `('COLIN', 58)` and what I believe that lambda is doing for each item: `('COLIN', 58)` ---> `(-58, 'COLIN')`. If I'm right and that is what the .sort() is using as the key, then what are the steps that the sort method takes to sort it?
Something important to note is that this .sort() with the lambda as the key sorts the items to have an end result of:

```
[('CAROL', 270), ('AMANDAB', 172), ('AMANDBA', 172), ('PauL', 108), ('JOSEPH', 79), ('COLIN', 58)]
```

This means that it is sorting it alphabetically as well for the items which have the same number as shown :

```
('AMANDAB', 172), ('AMANDBA', 172)
```

The end result of the sorted list sored the above in that order even though they had the same number they were also sorted alphabetically. I am lost to how that is done with that lambda. Please could someone explain what it does to make both, sorting by number and also by alphabetical order for ones that have the same number, possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuples are sorted lexicographically, ie. similarly to strings - by first element, if first elements are equal, then by second element etc. So sorting by `(-x[1], x[0])` sorts by `-x[1]` first (`-` to get reverse order), but if `x[1]` are identical then `x[0]` decides.

Comment: oh so if the numbers are equal then it checks for the string? and in the string compares the letters?

Comment: Exactly so (and capital letters are considered, maybe a bit counterintuitively, smaller than lowercase, so `'A' < 'a'`).